# How do I rewrote this peace of code in swift 2

Tags: swift

I am trying to make my first app and I am stuck. I don't know how to rewrite this piece of code from an earlier version of Swift in Swift 2.

```
func rowCheck(value value:Int) -> (location :String,pattern :String)?{
    let acceptableFinds = ["101","110","011"]
    var findFunc = [checkGornjiR,checkSrednjiR,checkDonjiR,checkLevuK,checkSrednjuK,checkDesnuK,checkLevuD,checkDesnuD]
        for algorithm in findFunc{
            let algorithmResults = algorithm(value:value)
            if find(acceptableFinds,algorithmResults.pattern) { // Error on this line
             return algorithmResults
            }

        }
        return nil
```

In "if" line I am getting error:

> "Optional type 'C.index?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!=nil' instead

A bit of help would be nice! Thanks!

Comment: what is the return value of `find( _, _)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you van use `contains` which return `Bool` value like this:

```
   if acceptableFinds.contains(algorithmResults.pattern) {
```